# Odoo: the best delete data practice

Tags: postgresql, odoo

First I should say 'I'm new in the Odoo.'
I have a data which can't be deleted from database. In some framework like DevExpress, They achieve delete method by making inactive data. 
So How do I achieve this result in Odoo? 
I know little about unlink method. So What's the best practice in Odoo?
If it's possible please share some method.

Comment: Depends on the data and this topic seems a bit broad don't you think? Relational data can't be deleted because of sql constraints or other things. A possibility in Odoo in such cases is either anonymization or pseudonymization of that data for example in context of data protection laws. There is no real implementation of that yet, maybe in community modules. Another implemented method is deactivation or archiving of records like partners. You probably stumbled over this already. And then there is the deletion of records by using the ORM method `unlink`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make records inactive in odoo those records will not be deleted but they will never effect anything in Odoo unless specifically searched for